# error #1009, even after removing event listeners

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

In a flappy bird game I'm making, I previously got a problem of `error #1009`. I solved some of it by the `removeEventListeners` while toggling between frames but there are still some of the problems.[Here's my file.](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3UsCGtgX4OrN3d6SDY5ckRNT0k). Please help.
 The problem's are seen in the `slide`, `obstposi` and `range` functions. The codes are here:

`slide` AND `obstposi` functions:

```
var start = false;
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, slide);
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, obstposi);

function slide(event: Event) {
    if (dead != true) {
        p1.x -= 5;
        p2.x -= 5;
        p3.x -= 5;
        p4.x -= 5;
        p5.x -= 5;
        p6.x -= 5;
        p7.x -= 5;
        p8.x -= 5;
        scorein1.x -= 5;
        scorein2.x -= 5;
        scorein3.x -= 5;
        scorein4.x -= 5;
    }
    if (flappy.hitTestObject(p1)) {
        dead = true;
    } else if (flappy.hitTestObject(p2)) {
        dead = true;
    } else if (flappy.hitTestObject(p3)) {
        dead = true;
    } else if (flappy.hitTestObject(p4)) {
        dead = true;
    } else if (flappy.hitTestObject(p5)) {
        dead = true;
    } else if (flappy.hitTestObject(p6)) {
        dead = true;
    } else if (flappy.hitTestObject(p7)) {
        dead = true;
    } else if (flappy.hitTestObject(p8)) {
        dead = true;
    }
}
function obstposi(event: Event) {

    if (flappy.hitTestObject(scorein4)) {
        scorein1.x = 702.3;
        p1.x = 650;
        p2.x = 650;
        p1.y = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 300) + 305;
        p2.y = p1.y - 335;

        start = true;
    } else if (flappy.hitTestObject(scorein1) && start == true) {
        scorein2.x = 702.3;
        p3.x = 650;
        p4.x = 650;
        p4.y = Math.ceil(Math.random() * -300) + 305;
        p3.y = p4.y - 335;

    } else if (flappy.hitTestObject(scorein2) && start == true) {
        scorein3.x = 702.3;
        p5.x = 650;
        p6.x = 650;
        p6.y = Math.ceil(Math.random() * -300) + 305;
        p5.y = p6.y - 335;

    } else if (flappy.hitTestObject(scorein3) && start == true) {
        scorein4.x = 702.3;
        p7.x = 650;
        p8.x = 650;
        p8.y = Math.ceil(Math.random() * -300) + 305;
        p7.y = p8.y - 335;

    }
}
```

`range` function:

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, range);

function range(event: Event) {
    if (limit.hitTestObject(flappy)) {
        flappy.x -= 2.5;
    }
    else if (wall.hitTestObject(flappy)) {
        flappy.y += 20;
    }
}
```

Comment: We aren't going to just download your file and debug it for you. You have to go into specifics to get questions answered. You must show effort in your debug attempts.

Comment: Try to add relevant info like which line(s) caused the error. Look at your `range` function which of those 9 lines of code gave you the _tried to access a non-existent something_ error? What are you doing to make sure it exists for the code?

Comment: I traced the object `flappy` and it returned `null`, is it the problem?

Comment: Yes, if flappy is null then you have a problem. Do you remove the flappy at some point? In that case also remove the event listeners. Or just make ONE enterframe listener, check if your flappy is not null and only if it exists call your slide and obstposi functions

Comment: Thanks! I will try this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem of your code is that you made the function work even if the objects like `flappy`, `ground`, etc. are not present in your scene. So, before starting you can add `if(flappy != null)` to make your code work only when `flappy` is present in the stage.